# Unable to install PHP-GD on Centos 7 with PHP 5.6.40

Tags: centos7, gd, php56

I have a PHP 5.6.40 server on which I am trying to install/enable the GD image library....with no success.

I've tried to install the following package

```
yum install php-gd
yum install php5-gd
yum install php56-php-gd
```

The first package (php-gd) errors out with dependency resolution errors.

```
Error: Package: php-gd-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.1.el7_7
           Installed: php-common-5.6.40-12.el7.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php56)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.6.40-12.el7.remi
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.el7.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.el7
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.1.el7_7.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.1.el7_7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

The second package (php5-gd) shows with the 'No package available' error.

The latter installs all the way through, but the GD module is still not enabled after restarting the HTTPD service and running phpinfo();

```
Package php56-php-gd-5.6.40-14.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

Any ideas how to get this installed and running.

My Base os is Centos 7 (CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810)

I'm really not sure how to get this module installed.

Any help appreciated.

Kind Regards

James

Comment: Are you using `php-fpm`? You may need to restart that specifically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have install **PHP 5.6.40** from a repository which is not enabled (**@remi-php56**), so you have to enable it for additional extension

As explained by the [wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php56
yum update
yum install php-gd
```

Notice: **PHP 5.6 is now EOL** so I hearthly recommend to upgrade to a [supported version](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)  (7.1+)

P.S. this will also pull 5.6.40-14 (instead of 5.6.40-12) which includes some more security fixes.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for this - it worked perfectly. We are already working on converting our legacy bespoke application to be PHP 7.1+ ready so will be moving away from PHP 5.6 very soon. Thanks again for your time and recommendations. Kind Regards, James